# window.location.href with Chrome Extension - New tab

Tags: redirect

I've got an input box, where I can type something into.

```
<input type="text" id="query">
```

I then grab that with

```
query = document.getElementById("query").value;
```

and redirect with

```
window.location.href = "http://site.com/" + query;
```

It happens when I do my button onclick="func();"

It works when I have a regular .html file, but when I put it into my Chrome Extension, it won't redirect. It's not even doing anything.

I've tried to put

```
chrome.tabs.create( { url: "http://www.site.com"} );
```

into my function, but it won't load that either.
My manifest.json has

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs"
]
```

Thank you

Comment: this will help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836180/setting-window-location-href-of-the-current-tab-in-a-browser-action-chrome-exten