# Why does window.location.href not work for my Google Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a **Google Extension** and I am using `window.location.href` to redirect them to a website. The first 2 lines of code work, but the `window.location.href` doesn't. 
I have no idea how to fix this, I am stumped.

```
var reply = prompt("Please put in the clothings ID");
var idofreply = reply - 1;
window.location.href = 'http://nbcasset.x10.bz/' + idofreply;
```

This line does not work: `window.location.href = 'http://nbcasset.x10.bz/' + idofreply;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836180/setting-window-location-href-of-the-current-tab-in-a-browser-action-chrome-exten

Comment: Where are you executing this code? In a background script?

Comment: Yes I am, I am doing this in a background script.